# PWA ReactJS Push Notification Using Firebase (FCM)

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, service-worker

I have created custom service worker file named as **firebase-messaging-sw.js** in public folder of create-react-app project. I configured firebase and get token.

**firebase-messaging-sw.js**

```
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.5.0/firebase-app.js');
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.5.0/firebase-messaging.js');

firebase.initializeApp({
    apiKey: "f",
    authDomain: "i",
    databaseURL: "r",
    projectId: "e",
    storageBucket: "b",
    messagingSenderId: "a",
    appId: "s",
    measurementId: "e"
});
const messaging = firebase.messaging()

messaging.setBackgroundMessageHandler((payload) => {
    console.log('in background handler:', payload)
    const promiseChain = clients
        .matchAll({
            type: "window",
            includeUncontrolled: true
        })
        .then(windowClients => {
            for (let i = 0; i < windowClients.length; i++) {
                const windowClient = windowClients[i];
                windowClient.postMessage(payload);
            }
        })
        .then(() => {
            return registration.showNotification("my notification title");
        });
    return promiseChain;
})
```

Using postman, I make a request to **https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send**.

I received notification on desktop system when tab is not focused and I cannot get notification on android and ios devices.

**Note:** *I've used Add to Home Screen from browsers (safari for ios) and (chrome for android) to use my PWA.*

Is there any other implementation is required for mobile devices ?